# Nomenclature sequence in Lyx

Tags: lyx, nomenclature

I am using the Nomenclature package in Lyx. I am sorting my entries between Greek symbols, Roman symbols and acronyms. As you can see in the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

the symbols are further separated: with or without subscription. How can I change the sequence so that all symbols are alphabetically ordered?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess:  you forgot `$` around `A`.  So `$X_t$` and `$Y_t$` are sorted as symbols, while `A` is sorted as a letter.  Try `$A$` in your `\nomenclature` command.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you could also tell me how to change the order for symbols with \bar{...}. At the moment those are separated and listed first.

Comment: This is described in the documentation :)  With the default prefix use `\nomenclature[a$x$]{$\bar{x}$}{Definition}`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I checked the documentation and internet but didn't find a solution. They are either at the beginning or at the end.
An example I use: $\nomenclature[g]{$\bar{\varepsilon}$}{average strain tensor}

Comment: \nomenclature[g$\epsilon$]{$\bar{\varepsilon}$}{average strain tensor}

Comment: Cool. Thanks! I added it as TeX code and it worked as I wanted it to be.